# ASP.NET Page.IsPostBack

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have some code in the load event of my page which should only run the first time the page is loaded, however, it runs everytime 'refresh' is clicked on the browser EVEN THOUGH i am checking for postbacks:

```
If not page.ispostback then
 ' Code...
End if
```

Comment: why are users refreshing the page and why is it so important that your code only run on the first hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Refresh** isn't a postback (i.e. there's no `POST` happening, it's another `GET`), it's the browser asking for the page all over again.  In this case, from the server point of view, it's a fresh request.

Comment: @burntsugar - What are you trying to only run once?  Maybe there's another approach.

Comment: Seems like he wants to prevent refreshs and/or treat them like PostBacks.

Comment: Now reading: Trap the Browser Refresh http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379557%28VS.80%29.aspx#bedrockas_topic2

Answer (score 0):

The `IsPostBack` property can only detect requests that were generated by a `__doPostBack` JavaScript function call.  All other requests are treated as new requests since ASP.NET has no way of knowing how the request was generated.

Since the `__doPostBack` function populates hidden form fields, the ASP.NET runtime is able to detect that the request was generated by a control which posted back.  All other requests will not have populated these hidden fields so the runtime does not consider them post-backs.